# My code doesn't execute my JS function before submitting form to the database

Tags: javascript, php, onsubmit

I have a problem executing the javascript code -`processPhase8()` - before submitting the data to the database. Data is sent to the database but JS is not executed so "decide" does not show on the database. Any help will be appreciated. New to programming.

Once the submit button is clicked, I want my JS function to do some scoring and send the outcome to `<h1 class="alert-heading" id="decide" name="decide"></h1>` so the `if (isset($_POST["submit"))` can send `$decide = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["decide"])` to the database:

```
// this is the javascript code I want to execute once the submit button is clicked before sending the form data to the database

function processPhase8()
{
    if(creditscore >= possibleScore) {
        _("decide").innerHTML="response1";
        return true;
    }
    else if( creditscore === possibleScore) {
        _("decide").innerHTML= "response2 "
        ;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        _("decide").innerHTML= "response3";
        return true;
    }
}
}

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $decide = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["decide"]);
    $query  = "INSERT INTO users(decide) VALUES('$decide')";
    mysqli_query($connection,  $query ); // connect DB and process query
    //create a variable to see if it went through
    $result =  mysqli_query($connection,  $query ); // assign variable

    if ($result) {
        echo "<p style=font-size:30px;>Hurray, It Works!</p>"; } // checking that the query worked
    } else {
        echo " it didn't work";
    }
?>

<head> 
<script src="signupmulti.js"> </script>
</head>
<html>
<form method="post" action="signup.php" id="multiphase" onsubmit="return processPhase8()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <h1 class="alert-heading" id="decide" name="decide"></h1>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Click here for a decision </button>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Once the submit button is clicked, I want my JS function to do some scoring and send the outcome to <h1 class="alert-heading" id="decide" name="decide"></h1> in my HTML

Comment: The first thing I notice is ' onsubmit="return processPhase8()" ' should be changed to ' onsubmit="processPhase8" '.

Comment: You have a syntax error on your `processPhase8()` function. One too many `}`.

Comment: Thank you guys. Your response really helped. I have solved the problem. thank you once again